# How to update horizon.php in Laravel and how to count proccesses in a queue?

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, horizon, laravel-horizon, laravel-jobs

I wrote new schedule and pulled it to test server and it works perfectly, BUT when I pulled it to production it does not work. I watched metrics in laravel-horizon and there was not new Job. So I decided that I had a bit processes therefor I changed my horizon.php processes from 3 to 5, BUT it changed to 10. Also I cleared my config and cache and metrics became empty, and some my old job does not work now too.

Comment: What is a name of the queue? Is it new so you do not create new queue worker for example?

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: did you restart the queue workers?

Comment: In case of @lagbox comment:

`sudo supervisorctl reread`

`sudo supervisorctl update`

`sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*`

Comment: I'm guessing the only difference between your local and production environments are the .env file and the queue worker. Can you switch the production driver to sync? Jobs are being processed then, then you have a worker issue. You can also try dispatching the job as soon as you create it, again, if it works it could be a worker issue. Edit your question with the driver details as well as your worker and the job payload

Comment: Temporarily stop supervisor and do the usual `php artisan queue:work` -- also make sure you don't have any typos in your supervisor config, if you do, correct them then restart the supervisor service

Comment: @doubleui I did not create new queue but it works in test

Comment: @lagbox Yeah, I did.

Comment: @doubleui I did it too. BUT It wrote that had not update

Comment: @CodeJunkieUnfortunately, I can not to add some another information, thank you. I will do that you wrote, also env files are absolutely identical